# Advanced method to control cache of enqueued style/script

Tags: functions, theme-development, css, wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

I have a WordPress website with medium-level traffic, ~10,000 unique visitors a day. Arround 30% of my daily visitors are recurrent. I constantly make some UI improvements: colors, font-size, javascript UX elements etc. Therefore on the same day, I can change .js and .css maybe 2 or 3 times. The problem is: the recurring visitors are viewing cached versions of the css/javascript files).

I've found this real useful script:

```
function my_load_scripts($hook) {
 
    // create my own version codes
    $my_js_ver  = date("ymd-Gis", filemtime( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'js/custom.js' ));
    $my_css_ver = date("ymd-Gis", filemtime( plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'style.css' ));
     
    // 
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom_js', plugins_url( 'js/custom.js', __FILE__ ), array(), $my_js_ver );
    wp_register_style( 'my_css',    plugins_url( 'style.css',    __FILE__ ), false,   $my_css_ver );
    wp_enqueue_style ( 'my_css' );
 
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_load_scripts');
```

This will make a versioning name based on the day the file its created, but I'm afraid to put it in public, because it will run everytime a user visit the website. And I'm afraid that the server can run out of resources.

Do you have another method?

Comment: what resource are you concerned the server will run out of? Are you asking for a specific answer that solves your question or just recommendations? You need to be able to mark an answer as the correct answer for all people with this question

Comment: I want to know if is there a better approach to make this thing done? I belive the snippet I just add work but I'm nervous if the server will run out of resources if the function is running everytime a user visit the webpage.

Comment: I'm not sure what resource you're referring to, the only way I see this being a problem is if this code created brand new files but it does not. Your anxiety is unfounded, when you can identify and name what it is you think will happen then you will have a question, otherwise you're going to have to be more specific. This change is intended to save you resources, why would it consume more? If a simple string selection was really that problematic you would notice a measurable change in page generation times, do you see such a change?

Comment: This is one of those situations where you should just try it, and notice that the difference in CPU is so tiny it's unmeasurable.